# Ad network traffic and Lambda invocation mismatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, rds

AWS Lambda is used as a link rotating solution for ad campaigns. I buy traffic from the ad networks, for example, Popads.

The problem here is that ad networks say that they have sent 350k daily visitors and I only get 120k Lambda invocations.

It is most likely that it is the problem with the ad network, but maybe AWS has to do something with this as well?

It is a huge difference between what we should get and what we get in reality. Maybe AWS has some default firewall like features that prevent visitors from invoking Lambda in the first place or something like that.

There are no errors on the Lambda's side, basically, invocations never happen and ones that happen - execute properly.

Does anyone know if it is solely a problem with ad networks or AWS might be responsible in any way?

Comment: did you integrate the lambda with api gateway ? Then you may check api gateway dashboard to see how many requests failed (5xx, 4xx) ?

Comment: I did not, I use direct Lambda links. Shouldn't these errors be visible on CloudWatch metrics for that Lambda function? Error and success rate metrics display errors that occur in that Lambda function.

Comment: I didn't get about direct Lambda links, are they invoked via aws sdk ? If your ad network is sending all the requests at once then you may get exceptions like "Rate exceeded" or 429 "TooManyRequestsException - but you won't see that in lambda but in your client side.

Comment: Inspected API Gateway logs and metrics. Same situation as Lambda metrics show. Huge difference between ad networks stats and data on AWS. 4xx and 5xx are extremely rare, count metric matches Lambda invocations.

Comment: My last two cents would be checking https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html and the way Ad networks are sending you data, if they are passing the limit or violating any of the limits of api gateway - that would be the reason.

Comment: They are sending it in a distributed manner. Seems like none of the limits are reached as well.